# Content Delivery Network configuration - CakePHP

Tags: html, cakephp

I want to use Cloudfront to serve images and CSS for my cakephp website. I would like to just host the files on my host and use cloud front to speed up delivery of said files, I dont know how to proceed?

Till now  I have created a distribution on CloudFront with my Origin Domain and CName and deployed it.

Origin Domain: example.com CName cdn.example.com

I added the CNAME for my domain:

cdn.mydomain.com with destination xx.cloudfront.net

Do I need to update the links in my HTML to that cname so if the stylesheet was http://example.com/app/webroot/css/style.css do I change that to http://cdn.example.com/app/webroot/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

You can go through and update your links to point to the CDN you would have to do this for every image and CSS/JS that you are serving from your CDN.

Another option would be to create a redirect in your .htaccess, perhaps something link this?:

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ http://cdn.mydomain.com/css$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I'm no .htaccess wizard so don't just copy and paste and expect it to work, but it should give you an idea of what you could do.